# Nginx/.htacces redirects not working properly

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

I'm having trouble figuring out what is wrong with my Nginx Virtualhost or/and Wordpress rewrite rules, it goes as follows:

http://example.com -> https://www.example.com works;

http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com works;

https://example.com -> https://www.example.com doesn't work at all!

I tried digging logs as much as I could to no avail.

My Nginx Virtualhost:

```
server {

# Uncomment the following line for domain mapping
# listen 443;

server_name example.com;
return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;

root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;

index index.php index.html index.htm;

include  common/wpsc.conf;     include common/wpsubdir.conf;
include common/wpcommon.conf;
include common/locations.conf;
include /var/www/example.com/conf/nginx/*.conf;



}
server {
# Uncomment the following line for domain mapping
# listen 443;

server_name www.example.com;

root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;

index index.php index.html index.htm;

include  common/wpsc.conf;     include common/wpsubdir.conf;
include common/wpcommon.conf;
include common/locations.conf;
include /var/www/example.com/conf/nginx/*.conf;
}
```

My htaccess Rewriterules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I used https://easyengine.io/ to install/configure everything and migrated my WordPress site from Cpanel.

What could I possible be missing out?

Comment: Without seeing all these it's anyone's guess! `include  common/wpsc.conf;`     `include common/wpsubdir.conf;`
`include common/wpcommon.conf;`
`include common/locations.conf;`
`include /var/www/example.com/conf/nginx/*.conf;`

Comment: Hello @miknik, how can I paste those files here without making the thread too big? I took a look at them and couldn't notice anything that could be causing this issue, but again, I'm a newbie at WP/nginx

Comment: Paste them somewhere like pastebin.com and edit your post with the link. From what you have included so far I can't see anything that would cause it to work. You have no ssl certificate directives, the listen directives in the server blocks are commented out, and even if they weren't they have no ssl parameter. Add `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to the list of files I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

First off, Nginx does not support .htaccess files.

Secondly, It's hard to say for sure why this isn't working, but here's what I'd check:

- Does example.com have an SSL cert? Often the redirect won't occur if
  SSL validation fails.
- Is the WordPress `siteurl` and `home` set to `https://www.example.com`?
- Are any errors showing up in the nginx error log?